# Why can't I create a MacOS framework with unresolved symbols?

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I thought one feature of dynamic libraries (and by extension Apple's Mach-O Frameworks) was to leave some symbols (methods) undefined until the using application gets linked, but it appears all symbols have to be resolved for `clang++` to successfully build a Framework.

For example, in building a framework for flight simulations, one might leave a C routine named `aero` undefined (but with an 'extern aero()' specification.) But XCode 4.2 refuses to build the framework, calling `_aero` an "undefined symbol."

Here's the header file included by both Objective-C and ANSI-C routines:

```
// FlightVehicleCAdapter_data.h

#ifndef FlightVehicleCAdapter_data_h
#define FlightVehicleCAdapter_data_h

#ifdef __cplusplus
external "C" {
#endif

extern void aero( void );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And here is where it gets called:

```
// FlightVehicleCAdapter.m

-(void) calcAero {
    aero();
    [self setBodyAeroForce_lb:   [lsVector3 vectorFromScalarX:fv_data->f_aero_v.x
                                                            Y:fv_data->f_aero_v.y
                                                            Z:fv_data->f_aero_v.z]];
    [self setBodyAeroMoment_ftlb:[lsVector3 vectorFromScalarX:fv_data->m_aero_v.x
                                                            Y:fv_data->m_aero_v.y
                                                            Z:fv_data->m_aero_v.z]];

}
```

I had hoped to be able to define the real `aero()` routine in the application that would link this framework, but when trying to build the *framework* itself the linker refuses to build it without a concrete `aero()` implementation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture [i386|x86_64]:
  "_aero", referenced from:
    -[FlightVehicleCAdapter calcAero] in FlightVehicleCAdapter.o
```

So I then defined a dummy `aero()` routine:

```
// dummy_aero.c
// not showing fv_data structure definition for clarity

void aero(void){
    fv_data->f_aero_v.x = 0.0; 
    fv_data->f_aero_v.y = 0.0;
    fv_data->f_aero_v.z = 0.0;

    fv_data->m_aero_v.x = 0.0;
    fv_data->m_aero_v.y = 0.0;
    fv_data->m_aero_v.z = 0.0;
}
```

This definition of `aero()` satisfies `clang++` such that the Mach-O framework (dynamic library) is successfully built. But when I link the resulting framework with the application target which includes a non-trivial `aero()` routine, the framework's dummy `aero()` is being called instead of the application's `aero()`.

Comment: It would help if you provide at least some details about what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: Where will `aero()` be defined?  Eventually, it has to be defined somewhere.

Comment: I edited the question to add code, thanks for the suggestion. Hope it clarifies the problem somewhat. I want to define aero() in a separate application that will link to this framework, thus providing the concrete aero() routine, but the framework won't build without the concrete implementations (which surprised me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `-bundle_loader <executable>` option to the linker, although I'm not sure that works for frameworks.  Alternatively, you can use `-undefined dynamic_lookup`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, Ken, `-undefined dynamic_lookup` fixed it. How obscure! Glad you knew about it, AND saw my question AND took the time to answer it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this for aero():

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void aero( void );

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This makes sure the function is declared in C++ to have a C-resolvable name.  C++ builds names differently than C does.

Note that then aero() can be linked at runtime.

Comment: "builds names" is called name mangling :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: @Vlad - Yes, and from there we can talk about ABIs and so forth but with the OP being apparently brand new to SO I was sort of thinking "walk before you run."  +1 for your comment anyway :)

Comment: This didn't seem necessary as I wasn't using C++ in this part of the project, but I tried your suggestion anyway (and included it in the example shown in the revised question) to no avail; the linker still wants a concrete definition of aero() before it will build the framework/dynamic library.